# Current object value in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

All,

in the below code How to edit the current added value.i.e, in the edit function how to get the value in td .Also how can we check for duplicates.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function edit(obj)
  {
     //   var ele= obj.parentNode ;
        alert(obj.innerHTML);
     var htm = '<textarea name="modal" id="modal" rows="10" cols="10" >'+ele.html+'</textarea>';
     $dialog.html(htm)
           .dialog({
              autoOpen: true,
              position: 'center' ,
              title: 'EDIT',
              draggable: false,
              width : 300,
              height : 400,
              resizable : false,
              modal : true,
              buttons: { "Save" : function() { if($('#modal').val() != ''){ obj.innerHTML=$('#modal').val() ;$dialog.dialog('close');} else {alert('i++'+$('#modal').val()+'++');} } }
           });
     $dialog.dialog('open');
  }


  $(document).ready(function() {
        var flag=0;

              if (flag == 0)
              {
                 var html = '<input type="text" name="val" id="val" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Add" id="add"><br>';
                 $('#useroptions').append(html);
                 flag=1;

                 $('#add').click(function(){
                    var a = $('#val').val();
                    if (a == '')
                    {
                       alert('Enter options');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       var section= '<tr class="clickable"><td id="userval" BGCOLOR="#FF6699">' + a + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <IMG SRC="edit.gif" onclick="javascript:edit(this);" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<IMG SRC="close.gif"
  onclick="javascript:del(this);" ></td></tr>';
                       $('#useroptions').append(section);
                    }
                      }
  }
  });
  });
  </script>

<table id="template">
<tr><td>
<div id="useroptions"></div>
</tr></td>

</table>
```

Comment: you're making a mistake... IDs are supposed to be unique, and in your code it's possible to add inputs with the same `add` id. the same with the tds.

Comment: actually it's just with the tds

Answer (score 0):

First off: you're mixing clunky inline `onXXX` handlers with more elegant jQuery event handlers. Why?

As for your "how to get the value in td" question: your `edit(obj)` will get the image passed as as the `obj` parameter, since the `onclick` is on the `img` element. You can find the container `td` like this: `var td = $(obj).closest('td')`. Then get its `.text()` or whatever you want.

But again: you could do this better using [live binding](http://api.jquery.com/live).